.NET 8 Blazor web app can't access PDF from server or local network
I'm trying to open a PDF file from an absolute path, when in debugging I can open it from both local network and the server I'm running the web app. But as soon as I host it in IIS, it can't access the PDF anymore (doesn't matter if it's local or on local network).
I'm using localsystem as identity since it has the highest permissions and the folder that has the PDF, every account I have has access to it, but still can't open it.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I know it has to do with permissions - I just don't know where else to look.
@code {
    string filepath = @"c:\\users\myusers\myfolder\ + filename;
    
    byte[] fileBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filepath);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
    string dataUri = $"data:application/pdf;base64,{base64}";

    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $@"
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src=""{dataUri}"" frameborder=""0"" style=""border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;"" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                ");
}

This is where I'm trying to open the PDF and the filename is the result of a query.

@"c:\\u..." - are you sure there should be a double slash with the verbatim string literal (is this just a typo in the question?) Can you also fix the code sample, there's a missing " before  + filename;, again, this is probably just a typo in the question but it doesn't help.

Hi @redrum1337, Ensure that the IIS application pool user has access to the folder where the PDF files are stored.

Try running Visual Studio as an administrator.
Verify IIS Configuration. Ensure that the application pool identity has read permissions for the directory and files, e.g., IIS AppPool\YourAppPoolName has the necessary read permissions.
To configure serving static files via HTTP, ensure that your config file allows static file access and that the MIME type for PDFs is configured correctly.
Here is an example of a config snippet:
"MimeTypes": {
    ".pdf": "application/pdf"
  }

Read and apply these settings in Program.cs:
var mimeTypes = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MimeTypes").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
if (mimeTypes != null)
{
    foreach (var mimeType in mimeTypes)
    {
        provider.Mappings[mimeType.Key] = mimeType.Value;
    }
}

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});

If you don't want to keep some of these configurations in appsettings.json, you can define them directly in Program.cs. However, this approach is not common for MIME type settings::
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider
    {
        Mappings = { [".pdf"] = "application/pdf" }
    }
});


Blazor does not use web.config, and this config would control serving the files via HTTP anyway, not their local access via file system.

In a .NET 8 Blazor Web App the configuration is primarily handled through the appsettings.json file.

Again, this configuration has nothing to do with the web server itself accessing the files via File.ReadAllBytes.

You are correct; the configuration I provided is primarily for serving static files via HTTP, not for accessing files via the file system using File.ReadAllBytes.
